# Passing Model to Controller Using ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Two simple methods, to create a new pack "Create" is called and for edit pack "Edit" method is called. This method calls "GetPackDetail" which gets pack related information. Edit method gets the pack information and assign it to model and opens the "Edit" page.

In Edit View page i am trying to pass whole model to "Create" method of Area controller. It works fine and i get all the information in that method when "Edit View" page is opened in edit mode. But i get null in "Name" field when user clicks to create a new pack by calling Create method in pack controller, then enter name of pack and then click on actionlink to pass this model to area controller. it seems like changes made to the model are not reflecting.

**Pack Controller Snippet**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        iSPYPack model = new iSPYPack();

        return View("Edit", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        var model = GetPackDetail(Id);            

        return View("Edit", model);
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
@model iSPYCMS.Models.iSPYPack

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  

  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)                                                

}          

 @Html.ActionLink("Create Area","Create","Area", Model, new { @class="btn btn-success"})
```

**iSPYPack Model**

```
 public class iSPYPack
 {        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pack Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Pack Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; 
 }
```

**Area Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create(iSPYPack Model)
    {

        var ispypackMode = Model;

        iSPYArea model = new iSPYArea();

        return View("Create", model);
    }
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Create Area","Create","Area", Model, new { @class="btn btn-success"})`is passing the original model, not what you have edited.

Comment: how can i pass edited model then?

Comment: Many options. Use javascript to construct a url based on the textbox and use `location.hef=url;` or have 2 submit buttons each with a unique `name` attribute and then in the `Edit()` post method, check the value of the button and redirect to the `Create()` method is appropriate. And you method should be `Create(string name)`, not `Create(iSPYPack Model)`

Comment: Why not just using the form? the form will pass the whole model. Then you can check if the id > 0, if it is it is edited, otherwise it's a new one

Comment: @StephenMuecke i used the approach to have two submit buttons, inside the one form. all works great but problem is if i put some other button inside that form, it also trigger the Edit post method.

Comment: What other buttons? If they have `type="button"` then they will not submit the form (the default action is `type="submit"` so you need to specify the type explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

Change posting the form to code below. Do replace the controller name. Instead of the action link, you will notice I have used  element instead. But kept your bootstrap classes for you. Just let you know, you combined two approaches of posting. You should use one or the other approach. Let me know if you need further help

```
@model iSPYCMS.Models.iSPYPack

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerNameOfCreateMethod", FormMethod.Post))
{  

  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)      

<input type="submit" value="Create New Pack" class="btn btn-success"/>                                        

}
```

However if for your requirements you need action link then this will help.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create  New Pack", "Create", "ControllerOfCreateMethod", new { area = "Admin", Name = Model.Name }, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "btn btn-success" } })
```